# ItextSharp only retrieving header text from my pdf

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I'm trying to read pdfs from a certain source with ItextSharp 4.2.0 (because of the GPL License) but I'm only retrieving header text from my pdfs.

I'm really newbie with PDF Structure but I suspect this is due to encoded streams inside :
When I Open my pdf in a text editor i see these kind of markups :

```
<</Filter/FlateDecode/I 94/Length 84/S 55>>stream
[Gibberish text]
endstream
endobj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 2592/N 3>>stream
endstream
endobj
```

my code is as simple as that :

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(tb_filename.Text);
for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
{
   var content = reader.GetPageContent(page);
   //do stuff depending on content
}
```

I'm pretty sure the data I'm trying to retrieve is actual text because i can copy/paste it from adobe reader to notepad.

What could I be missing here ?

Comment: For reference, I switched to pdfsharp and located the text I'm trying to extract inside an xobject contained in the resource node of the pdf.

Comment: this pdf is password protected ?

Comment: No it isn't, I just think it's strangely constructed, apparently it's made with FPDF.
Anyway I managed to retrieve my text by building a custom parser using PdfSharp